# ng update @angular/fire --allow-dirty --force made many errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, npm, package.json

i face  the error FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions only on page reload : so i decided  to update the npm module  with  this  command  " ng update @angular/fire --allow-dirty --force"
;and  then my project got much errors  , i wanna go back  to  the last version  ,  any help please ?

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: hello , i know  that  but i thought it was a  simple  question ,  i said  what i did exactly n  i don't  need to post  code  bro , hope to get  solution here